# C ++ simple function returning huge value - always the same value no matter the inputs - 4309838

Tags: c++, function

I am learning to code and this is a very simple function but it keeps returning the same answer every time, 4309838, and I don't know why. It is meant to calculate a paycheck, adding 50 whenever there is overtime. Any help is appreciated.

```
float payCheck(int ratePar, float hoursPar)
{
    if (hoursPar>40)
        payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar + 50;
    else
        payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar;
        return payCheck;
}
int main()
{   
int rate;
    float hours, pay;

    cout<<"Enter hours worked and pay rate "<<endl;
    cin>>hours>>rate;
    pay = payCheck(rate, hours);

    cout<<"Your paycheck is "<<pay<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You have not declared payCheck variable in payCheck function so how did it even compile?

Comment: This doesn't compile.  Post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar + 50;` this statement is trying to assign value to a `payCheck()` function. Declare the `payCheck` variable first.

Comment: Why are you naming your variables (`payCheck`) the same as your function?

Comment: This isn't Delphi or Pascal. Function return values come from `return something`,  you don't assign them to the function name treated as a variable. And fyi, a ternary expression reduces your entire function to simply `return ratePar*hoursPar + ((hoursPar > 40) ? : 50 : 0);`. Personally, I wanna be the guy that works 41 hours. That one extra hour apparently gets him a fifty-spot in his wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared payCheck variable in payCheck method. This works:

```
float payCheck(int ratePar, float hoursPar)
{
float payCheck;

if (hoursPar>40)
    payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar + 50;
else
    payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar;
return payCheck;
}
```

Comment: To avoid float to int auto conversion use float() like this:  payCheck = (float) ratePar*hoursPar + 50;

Comment: When is it good to name your variables the same as the function you're calling?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable which you are returning in the function.

```
float payCheck(int ratePar, float hoursPar)
{
float payCheck; //Observe this
if (hoursPar>40)
    payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar + 50;
else
    payCheck = ratePar*hoursPar;
return payCheck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the missing declaration of the *payCheck* local variable is the primary cause for the problem in the question I disagree with the answers that just introduce such a local variable like this (variable name changed to disambiguate from the function name):

```cpp
float payCheckAmount;
// or alternatively:
// float payCheckAmount = 0.0f  // looks better at first, but is not

// ... do something in an if-else

return payCheckAmount;
```

The problem is that *payCheckAmount* is in a nonsensical state (from the point of view of the function’s purpose) until an actual assignment of a calculated value happens somewhere in the *if* construct. This is an error waiting to happen. At some point someone *will* change the *if* construct in a way that doesn’t cover all possible conditions anymore and the nonsensical initial value of *payCheckAmount* value will be returned, leading to a hard to track down error somewhere else in the program.

Whenever possible write your program in a way that makes it impossible to end up in an illegal state. When doing that try to anticipate likely future changes to the code as well.

For the *payCheck()* function you could get rid of the local variable entirely:

```cpp
float payCheck(int ratePar, float hoursPar)
{
    if (hoursPar > 40) {
        return ratePar*hoursPar + 50;
    }

    return ratePar*hoursPar;
}
```

However, this has the disadvantage that the rate*hours calculation is duplicated in the code. If it ever changes you’ll have to remember to change both locations. For that reason I’d go for this implementation:

```cpp
float payCheck(int ratePar, float hoursPar)
{
    float payCheckAmount = ratePar*hoursPar;

    if (hoursPar > 40) {
        payCheckAmount += 50;
    }

    return payCheckAmount;
}
```

As long as the basic logic of your calculation remains “base pay per hour plus overtime bonus” you can’t end up returning a nonsensical value.